# Jackson no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value

Tags: java, jackson

I have this as partial JSON:

```
 "nextStages":[1]
```

I have this in my Java:

```
private List<Integer> nextStages;
.....
public List<Integer> getNextStages() {
    return nextStages;
}
public void setNextStages(List<Integer> nextStages) {
    this.nextStages = nextStages;
}
```

and I am getting this error:

```
 Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: 
 Cannot construct instance of `com.my.workflow.bean.json.StageObject` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)
```

So how do I do this for proper serialization/deserialization ?

Comment: Do you have a default constructor?

Comment: No constructor, so yes, I just have the default constructor.

Comment: The mesage is telling you that Jackson needs to create a StageObject, from a single number value. So what is says doesn't match with what you're claiming in your question. Post the whole JSON document, and the whole classes mapped to this JSON document.

Answer (score 1):

You need to post the whole `JSON` and `Classes` for us to know more about your error.

This works fine for me:

**test.json**

```
{
  "nextStages":[1]
}
```

**StageObject.java**

```
public class StageObject {

    private List<Integer> nextStages;

    public List<Integer> getNextStages() {
        return nextStages;
    }
}
```

Here I am reading the JSON file, mapping it to StageObject and writing it to output.

```
public class ReadTestJSON {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        StageObject stageObject = mapper.readValue(new File("test.json"), StageObject.class);
        mapper.writeValue(System.out,stageObject);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "nextStages" : [ 1 ]
}
```

Hope this helps.